# Wordpress Meta Query Relation with Multiple Arguments

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking for a solution by which I can apply 'OR' relation depending upon the meta key,
In the below code you can see that `'relation' =>'AND'` is applied which makes AND clause for every meta key like `asset_category` , `asset_type` .
If the post has true value for both asset_category and asset type then only post will be found in query.

What I want is different relation for different meta keys, for example:
Meta key `active_inactive` should be always true,
Meta key `asset_category` is optional so AND clause needs to apply on it

Can someone help me to make the code?
Any help appreciated.

```
$args = array(      
                'post_type'   => 'asset',
                's' => $keyword,
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'orderby'=>  'title' ,
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'post_status' =>'publish',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' =>'AND',
                    array(
                        'key' => 'active_inactive',
                        'value' => 'Active',
                        'compare' => '=',
                    ),
                )
            ); 
            if(isset($_GET['category'])){
                if(is_array($_GET['category'])){
                    foreach($_GET['category'] as $cat){
                        $args['meta_query'][]=array(
                          
                            'key' => 'asset_category',
                            'value' => $cat,
                            'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                );
                    }
                }else{
                    $args['meta_query'][]=array(
                        'key' => 'asset_category',
                        'value' => $_GET['category'],
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    );
                    
                }
            }
            if(isset($_GET['assetType'])){
                if(is_array($_GET['assetType'])){
                    foreach($_GET['assetType'] as $cat){
                        $args['meta_query'][]=array(
                            'key' => 'asset_type',
                            'value' => $cat,
                            'compare' => 'LIKE',
                        );
                    }
                }else{
                    $args['meta_query'][]=array(
                        'key' => 'asset_type',
                        'value' => $_GET['asset_type'],
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    );
                }
            }
            if(isset($_GET['levels'])){
                $args['meta_query'][]=array(
                    'key' => 'difficulty_level',
                    'value' => $_GET['levels'],
                    'compare' => 'IN',
                );
            }
            
            $wp_query_arr[] = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Are _all_ of those expect `active_inactive` optional, or just some of the others?

Comment: You need to move your optional conditions down a level, and use OR on that level. You do not want `active_inactive AND something OR anotherthing`, you want `active_inactive AND (something OR anotherthing)` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters has an example (the last one.)

Comment: @CBroe yes the logic you had written is exact same I am looking for but I am not getting how to implement it with my code, will you please do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$filter[] =  array(
           'key' => 'active_inactive',
           'value' => 'Active',
            'compare' => '=',
        );
if(isset($_GET['category'])){
            if(is_array($_GET['category'])){
                foreach($_GET['category'] as $cat){
                    $filter[]=array(
                        'key' => 'asset_category',
                        'value' => $cat,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                ),
            );
                }
            }else{
                $filter[]=array(
                    'key' => 'asset_category',
                    'value' => $_GET['category'],
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                );
                
            }
        }
        if(isset($_GET['assetType'])){
            if(is_array($_GET['assetType'])){
                foreach($_GET['assetType'] as $cat){
                    $filter[]=array(
                        'key' => 'asset_type',
                        'value' => $cat,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    );
                }
            }else{
                $filter[]=array(
                    'key' => 'asset_type',
                    'value' => $_GET['asset_type'],
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                );
            }
        }
        if(isset($_GET['levels'])){
            $filter[]=array(
                'key' => 'difficulty_level',
                'value' => $_GET['levels'],
                'compare' => 'IN',
            );
        }  
        if(count($filter) > 1 ){
            $args = array(      
                'post_type'   => 'asset',
                's' => $keyword,
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'orderby'=>  'title' ,
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'post_status' =>'publish',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' =>'AND',
                    $filter,

                )
            ); 

        } else {
            $args = array(      
                'post_type'   => 'asset',
                's' => $keyword,
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'orderby'=>  'title' ,
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'post_status' =>'publish',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    $filter
                )
            ); 

        }
        $wp_query_arr[] = new WP_Query($args);
```